# Adding std deviation to mean of pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe, like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,5),columns=['blue','white','red','green','purple'])
df['group_labels']=['a','a','b','c','b','c','a','c','b','b']
```

I'd like to group by 'group_labels', calculate the mean and then display in a new dataframe (mean +- std deviation of the mean). So basically I'd like to have:

```
mean_df=df.groupby('group_labels').mean().reset_index()
```

but, in each cell, I need to display also

```
+- std deviation of the group / sqrt(size of the group)
```

Is that possible?

Comment: see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with custom function created by [`std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.std.html), default `ddof` is `1`:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
df=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,5),columns=['blue','white','red','green','purple'])
df['group_labels']=['a','a','b','c','b','c','a','c','b','b']


def func(x):
    return x.std() / len(x)**(1/2)
```

Alternative:

```
def func(x):
    return x.std() / np.sqrt(len(x))
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('group_labels').agg(['mean', func])
print (df1)
                  blue               white                 red            \
                  mean      func      mean      func      mean      func   
group_labels                                                               
a             0.450134  0.174723  0.401106  0.214163  0.417548  0.009156   
b             0.532030  0.185240  0.595667  0.174218  0.496617  0.150546   
c             0.552874  0.247173  0.382590  0.099883  0.571595  0.222161   

                 green              purple            
                  mean      func      mean      func  
group_labels                                          
a             0.786139  0.156584  0.525661  0.234515  
b             0.505838  0.215673  0.653970  0.114664  
c             0.653841  0.132705  0.587994  0.111854
```

For remove `MultiIndex` in columns use:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df1)
              blue_mean  blue_func  white_mean  white_func  red_mean  \
group_labels                                                           
a              0.702381   0.201604    0.679590    0.159292  0.743523   
b              0.386550   0.057390    0.418805    0.126278  0.306843   
c              0.636310   0.269986    0.385225    0.240675  0.451133   

              red_func  green_mean  green_func  purple_mean  purple_func  
group_labels                                                              
a             0.083068    0.788519    0.075999     0.738081      0.16673  
b             0.093714    0.792748    0.071369     0.465246      0.15333  
c             0.217406    0.293735    0.108021     0.549472      0.17632
```

Comment: Very clever, thanks a lot. I didn't think about adding another column. Do you think it's possible to unify the elements of columns _mean and _func in a single column, whose values are 'mean +- std dev'?

Comment: @sato - I am a bit confused with +-, can you explain more?

Comment: '±', the symbol for the intervals of confidence. Whenever you give a scientific measure, you have to give it in the form of 'value ± std dev'. I'd like to have them in one single cell, so for example the first cell of the first column would be (0.70±0.20).

Comment: @sato - Hmmm, give me some time.

Comment: @sato - It is possible, but not sure if useful, because is necessary convert numeric to strings and add `+-` manually like `df2 = (df1.xs('mean', axis=1, level=1).round(3).astype(str) + '±' +
       df1.xs('func', axis=1, level=1).round(3).astype(str))`

Comment: Ok cool, didn't know the df.xs() function. Thanks a lot for your help anyway!